# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'core.User' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

I want create custom fields in user_auth table.I just wrote a code in models.py and AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
   bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
   birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and in settings.py
 AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'

How can I get rid of this problem. I am new in django. Help me

Comment: THis is installed in an app named `core`? Is `core` placed in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig', # new
]

Comment: please send me code

Comment: well as said, `'core'` should be an element of `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Hello, Should I run migrate command after it? inorder to add extra field?

Comment: please tell me the next step

Comment: likely yes, since up till now, Django did not construct the models in your `core` app.

Comment: Thank you Willem. It works. It creates account_user table and add my custom fieId but I have one question, if I want to add two more custom fields further,  then should I have to run migrate command again?

Comment: Because at that moment it shows  auth_group already exist etc.

Comment: Hi it works thanks